# Spacing and brackets

Tags: spacing, brackets

I know this is a duplicate but I can't find the original post.
Square brackets do not display with the correct spacing around `=` or `\cong`.
For example :

`$[0,1[ \cong [a,b[ \hspace{5ex} ]0,1] \cong ]a,b] \hspace{5ex} ]0,1[ \cong ]a,b[$`

displays

[image]

Comment: `\mathopen{]}0,1]`  and `[0,1\mathclose{[}`

Comment: Here’s an even better solution: Don’t use that notation at all. Write `(0,1]` and `[0,1)`, like any normally functioning mathematician does.

Comment: @Gaussler Nice troll, I don't fall for that.

Answer (score 4):

by default [ is a mathopen and ] is mathclose, but you can force other interpretations

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$[0,1\mathclose[ \cong [a,b\mathclose[ \hspace{5ex} \mathopen]0,1] \cong 
  \mathopen]a,b] \hspace{5ex} \mathopen]0,1\mathclose[ \cong \mathopen]a,b\mathclose[$

\end{document}
```

In practice you would want to hide this in a suitable command eg using `mathtools` `\DeclarePairedDelmiter` :

```
\DeclarePairedDelmiter\oointerval][
\DeclarePairedDelmiter\ocinterval]]
\DeclarePairedDelmiter\cointerval[[
\DeclarePairedDelmiter\ccinterval[]
```